# What do I do to create an older browser, backwards-compatible jquery solution for an html 5 form?

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit, checkbox

HTML 5 makes life easier, but unfortunately it does not work with older browsers. I have a form which works correctly with any modern browser using HTML 5, but I need a solution that will still be compatible for older browsers:

```
<p>
<input name="array[]" type="checkbox" value="a1" form="myform" class="checkbox"/> a1<br />
<input name="array[]" type="checkbox" value="b1" form="myform" class="checkbox"/> b1<br />
<input name="array[]" type="checkbox" value="c1" form="myform" class="checkbox"/> c1<br />
</p>

<form id="myform" method="POST" action="test.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

The number of checkboxes are generated dynamically and cannot be placed into any form tag. I need to pass the checkbox values on submit with the form "myform". The above example works with html 5 browsers but not with older browsers.

How could I make this work for older browsers such as IE 7, etc. etc. ?

Could it could be done with jQuery? Any suggestions?

Comment: On submit, just go through the checkboxes, and create a hidden input field _inside_ the form for each checked box holding the checkbox value – and then let the form be submitted.

Comment: The problem here is that the checkboxes are not in a form tag. Any suggestion how to "go through the checkboxes" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create hidden inputs and use the current values from the checkboxes and then add them to the form before it's submitted with jQuery, like this:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    $form = $(this);

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (index, elem) {
        var val = $(elem).val(),
            name = $(elem).attr('name');

        var hiddenInput = $('<input type="hidden" value="' + val + '" name="' + name + '"/>');
        $form.append(hiddenInput);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but the example does not work. I cannot see any posted data with print_r($_POST);

Comment: It works... I forgot to put the script into the form tag. Thank you!